# What does "extended meaning" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I have an assignment and one question confuses me a lot. the question is:

> The words below have a literal as well as an extended meaning. Write the literal meaning of the words. Use the following words in sentences of your own using the ‘extended’ meaning.
>
> 1. angry
> 2. train
> 3. mouth

What does "an extended meaning" mean? And how can I use extended meaning to form a sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The website [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/extended) says that *extended* means:

> **extended** (*adj.*) beyond the literal or primary sense

So I suppose there are two ways a word could have an extended meaning:

- the word could be used in a figurative sense, rather than a literal sense
- the word could have a secondary meaning that we don’t immediately associate with the word

As for your exercise, the word *mouth* seems easy. People have a mouth, and so od lions – but rivers have a mouth as well.

> The mouth of the Rhine is at Hoek van Holland by the North Sea.

As for a word like *angry*, we only need to consult a good dictionary for ideas. From [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/angry):

> **angry** (*adj.*)
>
> 1. adj. Displaying or feeling anger.
> 2. Inflamed and painful.
> 3. Dark and stormy, menacing.

That third one looks like an extended meaning to me. So, we might say:

> When Stella noticed the angry clouds, she called her children inside.

The word *train*  has dozens of meanings, so it’s a little harder to figure out which ones are the “primary” definitions and which might the “extended” meanings. But I will say this about the noun *train*: a railroad yard has a train, but so does a wedding dress. Moreover, about the verb *train*: a woman might train a dolphin, but she also might train her hair.

Answer (score 7):

The use of *extended* is odd. Without more context, I would guess that what the assignment is talking about is a *figurative* meaning. (In contrast to *literal*.)

For instance, the words are not being used in a literal sense in the following sentences:

> It was an *angry* wound.
>   They got on board the pity *train*.
>   She was at the *mouth* of madness.